# What's the point of NPY_NO_EXPORT in NumPy's source code?

Tags: c, numpy

Analizing NumPy's source code [I came across](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L115-L116) some function definitions that used the `NPY_NO_EXPORT` macro. Something like this:

```
NPY_NO_EXPORT int
PyArray_MultiplyIntList(int const *l1, int n)
{
    int s = 1;

    while (n--) {
        s *= (*l1++);
    }
    return s;
}
```

I understand that the `NPY_NO_EXPORT` macro is supposed to be `static` or `extern`, and that the function will be exported accordingly. However what's the mechanism (on a wider range of view) that regulates how the NumPy C library exports its symbols? Taking NumPy as an example, what would be the best way to export the symbols of a C library efficiently?

Comment: The macro definition is probably in conditional code, so it gets defined as either `static` or `extern` depending on how the file is being compiled.

Comment: @Barmar what are the particular cases in which the file needs to be compiled with the macro as `static` or as `extern`?

Comment: I haven't looked at the code, but maybe it can be compiled as a library, which requires exporting, or a standalone program.